# Verify downloaded file contents on Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am automating withJenkins. I am downloading the file in jenkins using selenium, but I want verify the downloaded file. Can I do this using selenium.(Upon downloading the file, file will be jenkins's folders, i need to verify that file has downloaded or not).
I am able to download the file on my local drive on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

No, selenium cannot assert file presence in file system. You have to use Java file handling classes to traverse through the directories and assert if a file exists in the workspace folder or not. A sample pseudocode will be like this:

```
File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\Downloads") ;
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
for (File f : files) {
    fileName = f.getName();           
    if (fileName.startsWith(initials) && fileName.endsWith(".csv") && fileName.contains(strDate.substring(0,7))) {
        iCount++;
        System.out.println(strDate.substring(0,7));
        Reporter.log("Found file :"+fileName);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also check at jenkins job level. Just execute *a windows batch command* and run the `dir` command to search for that downloaded file in the current workspace folder.

```
dir <youFileName>  /s /p
```

Apply selective, `find` or `EQU` operation to assert if file exists or not.

Comment: Using java i am successfully able to download the file and read it ,but i am not ablr to find the file when my scripts executed on Jenkins.Could you please let me know to handle it on Jenks

Comment: Usually, files downloaded from Chrome browser goes into C:\Users\<YourAccount>\Downloads . If you have configured this properly , then you must be able to locate it on slave-agents. If your slave-agents are added via administrator priviledges, then downloaded files are getting into C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads.

Comment: thanks for the reply.Actually i am using firefox and chrome for  test execution.